# Differential form of the inverse Weierstrass P-function

Tags: differential-forms, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

I will begin by an giving some motivation:

Let $(x,y)$ be some point in the plane, the polar coordinates are defined implicitly by
$$r \cos \theta=x, \\r \sin \theta =y.$$
Suppose $r \neq 0$, and define $X=x/r,Y=y/r$. We then have
$$\cos \theta=X, \\ \sin \theta =Y, $$
and $X^2+Y^2=1$. Taking the differential of both equations gives
$$-\sin \theta \mathrm{d} \theta=\mathrm{d} X, \\ \cos(\theta) \mathrm{d} \theta=dY.$$
It is now evident that
$$\mathrm{d} \theta=-Y \mathrm{d} X+X \mathrm{d} Y ,$$ and this is a derivation of that well-known result. An interesting point here is that $\mathrm{d} \theta$ is well defined, even though $\theta$ itself isn't a single-valued function.

---

Now to my analogous question: Suppose instead that $X,Y$ lie on the Weierstrass elliptic curve $$Y^2=4X^3-g_2 X-g_3 $$ for some constants $g_2,g_3$. Then, there is some $\theta$, depending on $X$ and $Y$ satisfying
$$\wp(\theta;g_2,g_3)=X, \\
\wp'(\theta;g_2,g_3)=Y, $$
with $\wp$ being the Weierstrass P-function. Taking the differentials, we get
$$\wp'(\theta;g_2,g_3) \mathrm{d} \theta=\mathrm{d} X,  \\
\wp''(\theta;g_2,g_3) \mathrm{d} \theta=\mathrm{d} Y.$$

Furthermore, using the 2nd order ODE for $\wp$, the pair of equations simplifies to
$$\wp'(\theta;g_2,g_3) \mathrm{d} \theta=\mathrm{d} X, \\
\left( 6 \wp^2(\theta;g_2,g_3)-\frac{1}{2} g_2 \right) \mathrm{d} \theta=\mathrm{d}Y $$
I tried to manipulate these two algebraically to get a "nice" expression for $\mathrm{d} \theta$ in this case, but I couldn't do it. I was wondering if there's any simple expression for $\mathrm{d} \theta$ after all, and if there is, I'd like to see it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is $\quad d\theta = (-3Y dX + 2 X dY)/( 2g_2 X+3g_3)\quad$ nice enough?

Comment: I'll take it. Thank you. edit: it looks like it should be $2g_2 X$ in the denominator, right?

Comment: @user1337 Thanks! I made a typo.